# Salesforce Oauth 2.0 JWT

Tags: oauth, jwt, webserverflow

I am getting below -

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"user hasn't approved this consumer"}
```

Dev org To Dev Org, below are the connected app - 
[image]

Comment: Is your connected app set to let users self-authorize, or have an admin pre-authorize user roles (or is it profiles? I forget). In either case, have you gone through an interactive flow in your target org? If it's the former, have you (or the target user) gone through an interactive flow to explicitly authorize the connected app?

Comment: @nirmallya, Usually, the above error is seen when the settings are set to admin approved, and the users profile hasn’t been added through the connected app authorized profiles

Comment: Connected App settings are set to admin approved and added system admin profile.. still i am getting same error.

Comment: Repeating again what I previously said..."_*In either case, have you gone through an interactive flow in your target org?*_". Your Connected App needs to be approved once by someone using a different flow before you can use the JWT flow (and it may need to be a flow that normally generates a refresh token).